# making popover animation work

Tags: css, angularjs, css-animations

Upon click of button, I display a popover.

however if you notice the pointer of the popover slides from a completely different direction.

Not quiet able to fix this. Kindly advise.

```
.popover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: -175px;

  width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: rgb(233, 212, 222);
    border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 3px -2px 4px #AAA;
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
}

.popover-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: -16px;
    left: 180px;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid rgb(233, 212, 222);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
    transition: all linear 0.01s;
}
```

plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/SiwYgmkZjh2NuszI0q2E

Expected behavior would be for the pointer of the popover to also animate the same was the popover does (from top to bottom)

Comment: What do you want us to do? What is the desired behavior? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: @AndrewL. clicking on the link he provided, along with his line "if you notice the pointer of the popover slides from a completely different direction.", the issue is pretty obvious.

Comment: @TylerRoper I was looking for the expected behavior so we could help fix the problem, seeing now that the OP has added that to his question, I see no problem with it

Comment: @AndrewL. I hope you gave those negative points cause i truly deserve them and not cause you have personal matters that agonize you and you are just looking for an venue to vent

Comment: I removed the downvote after you added an expected behavior. Please do not accuse users of being personal in their decisions to downvote.

Answer (score 1):

THis is due to the ng-hide class that is added to your .popover class. It has set position before animation.

```
top: -18px;
left: 20px;
```

Override it with this:

```
.ng-hide {
    top: -16px;
    left: -175px;
}
```

Comment: that's surely a step in the right direction. it fixes behavior of arrow but changes behavior of the box

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Valius79 .. i got something working

```
.popover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: -175px;

  width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: rgb(233, 212, 222);
    border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 3px -2px 4px #AAA;
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
}
.popover.ng-hide {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  top:-18px;
  left: 20px;
}

.popover-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 5px;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid rgb(233, 212, 222);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
   transition: all linear 0.5s;
}


.popover-arrow.ng-hide {
  top: -36px;
  left: 5px;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/SiwYgmkZjh2NuszI0q2E?p=preview